# Storing checkbox value in mysql database if checked

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have checkbox and radiobox in my user settings form. If a user checks a box, I want to save its value into the mysql database. Later, I'll also need to retrieve it according to user selection. How can I do this?

Comment: For one, you can start by researching and some googling, and then post what you have tried here for us to help.

Comment: What code have you tried? We'll need to take a look at your example code that you'll need help on

Comment: you can go with Ajax. But, we need your code to guide you more.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a "give me teh codes" question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you'll need a section in your table for the user

radio_checked ( a bool would work, have a function when you read it back that 1 = yes and 0 = no. )

you will you use the POST_ function to post the information to the database as well so a sample code would look like this

```
<form>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
</form>

 <?php

 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","$username","$password","$my_db");



  if $_POST['sex'] {
        $gender = $_POST[sex]
        }

 mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Persons(gender) VALUES ('$_POST[sex]')");

?>
```

From there you will make a function that selects and calls the row and sets the value of your information and test the fields that you need